# cex.io web socket Authentication timestamp error

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm currently trying to connect to the CEX.IO bitcoin exchange's websocket. Websocket connection is OK but at the time of authentication, I have the error: Timestamp is not in 20sec range. I don't know what this error.

Test case 1 & 2 for createSignature is OK (https://cex.io/websocket-api#authentication).

Code for calculating the signature and request params

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const cexioWs = new WebSocket(
    'wss://ws.cex.io/ws/',
    {
        perMessageDeflate: false
    }
);
function createAuthRequest(apiKey, apiSecret) {
    let curTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret);
    hmac.update(curTime.toString());
    hmac.update(apiKey);
    let args =
        {
            e: "auth",
            auth: {
                key: apiKey,
                signature: hmac.digest('hex'), //createSignature(curTime, apiKey, apiSecret),
                timestamp: curTime
            }
        };
    let authMessage = JSON.stringify(args);
    console.log(args);
    return authMessage;
}
cexioWs.on('message', (mess, error) => {
    //console.log("connected");
    console.log("cexio message");
    console.log(mess);
    let JSONMess = JSON.parse(mess);
    if (JSONMess.e === "connected") {
        cexioWs.send(createAuthRequest(key, secret));
        cexioWs.send(JSON.stringify({
            e: "subscribe",
            roomss: [
                "tickers"
            ]
        }));
    }
    if (JSONMess.e === "ping") {
        console.log("pong message");
        cexioWs.send(JSON.stringify({e: "pong"}));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is working code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const WebSocket = require('ws')

var apiKey = ''
var apiSecret = ''

const cexioWs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.cex.io/ws/', {perMessageDeflate: false });

function createSignature(timestamp, apiKey, apiSecret){ 
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret );
    hmac.update( timestamp + apiKey );
    return hmac.digest('hex');
}

function createAuthRequest(apiKey, apiSecret ){
    var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var args = { e: 'auth', auth: { key: apiKey,
        signature: createSignature(timestamp, apiKey, apiSecret), timestamp: timestamp } };
    var authMessage = JSON.stringify( args );
    return authMessage;
}

cexioWs.on('message', (mess, error) => {
        console.log("cexio message");
        console.log(mess);
    let JSONMess = JSON.parse(mess);
    if (JSONMess.e === "connected") {
        cexioWs.send(createAuthRequest(apiKey, apiSecret));
        cexioWs.send(JSON.stringify({
            e: "subscribe",
            rooms: [
                "tickers"
            ]
        }));
    }
    if (JSONMess.e === "ping") {
        console.log("pong message");
        cexioWs.send(JSON.stringify({e: "pong"}));
    }
});
```

Comment: This code also does not work.Gives an error message
 {"e":"auth","data":{"error":"Timestamp is not in 20sec range"},"ok":"error"}

Comment: EU:Vilnius UTC+02:00

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this helps but I had the same problem for two days, checked everything then I checked and the code looked absolutely fine. Later on I checked what the actual time I was getting and compared it to the Internet time. My computer's time was 4 minutes ahead of Internet time and my settings were off for 'update time from Internet'.

After sync'ing my computer's time with Internet I ran the script and it worked perfectly.

Moral of the story, make sure your PC's time and the Internet's time are the same.
Goodluck!